# Upload a file into a ftp server using buffered output with Curl

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl, pg-dump

I want to upload a database backup file into an external ftp server using curl. I use postgres and pg_dump streams the content of file into buffered output.
I tried

`echo pg_dump dbname| gzip" | curl -d @- ftp://user:pass@host:/pg_dump/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")_dump.gz`

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I tried

`pg_dumpall | gzip | curl -T ftp://user:pass@host:/pg_dump/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")_dump.gz`

and it worked.